# Jump Start My VS 2015 Community Experience

Tags: visual-c++

My last experience with visual programming was with VB 6.0. So it's been awhile. Now I need a C code developement environment to interface with another tool. It would be nice to work in a visual programming and event driven IDE similar to my VB experience. The other tool vendor suggested installing the free VS 2015 Community package. What is the best way to download, install and get me up and running in this C code environment?

Comment: See my answer below, but I wonder why you opted for C (or C++ as you tagged the question). C# is most likely more 'accessible' when you come from VB and is just as powerful. Nothing wrong with C(++) but you might not need the low level powers of C(++) for your goals to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Download Visual Studio Community 2017 here:

https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community

You don't need to install the full blown thing anymore, just pick the blocks your want to use. If you need more later on you can simply add more blocks.
It is free, and there are boatloads of samples around (check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ for instance) to get you started.

Comment: The other tool I am interfacing to supports event based and procedural step-by-step Standard C. It will allow me to reference some low level objects I need from the other tool's hardware. The tool vendor suggested using VS for it's nice feature set.

Answer (score 0):

Probably "microsoft official site" but i'd not recommended "comunity edition" just for one reason : [it's a bit overloaded], i know it may feels good to have space for growing up, but in fact (probably) you'll barely try a quarter stuffs they present for you. Before you become a "GURU" they will be just spotted your eyes and (a bit) slow down progress.

If you'll want do your codding on Windows 7 or earlier, you'd better try a (minimalistic) "Visual studio express 2013" (Same stuff, but more strict functionality). And... if you would try Visual studio express, it better to choose a version "x86", i cant say that does matters on "C", but if you'll start programming openGL, it's saves you a lot of nerves (64x has a several big errors)

Comment: I attemped execution of a project with <Local Windows Debugger>.

Comment: I got an error under <Local Windows Debugger> stating "unable to start progarm C:\.........\Debug\VaisalaDataParse.dll. The system cannot find the file specified"

Comment: But my DLL is actually in a different folder. Is there a setting I need to change? I'm using VS Express BTW.